# how to write in the database with the same persist order

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have this code I am persisting like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listofplusieurdrapage.size(); i++) {
    persist(listofplusieurdrapage.get(i));
}
```

I have two values in

```
litsofplusieurdrapage => litsofplusieurdrapage.get(0) = 1
=>litsofplusieurdrapage.get(1) = 2
```

but when i check the database I found them in this order:

- 2
- 1

and when I add just a `system.out.println` to the code I have the good order

```
for (int i = 0; i < listofplusieurdrapage.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(" Persist : " + listofplusieurdrapage.get(i));
    persist(listofplusieurdrapage.get(i));
}
```

- 1
- 2

do you have an explication of the problem ?
and how I can keep the good order with out adding the `system.out.println` to my code ?

```
public void persist(Object object) {
    em.persist(object); 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'when i check the database', how do you access the database ? what is the type of 'listofplusieurdrapage' ?

Comment: While do you not use an explicit order for records in the db (select ... order by) you will get them in their "natural" order. Propably they have a unique id column. JPA will retrieve by this id in ascend order. I suppose when you "look" into the DB the program to visualize the records (phpmyadmin ?) will order by the id in descend order.

Comment: i have the access to Mysql and i show the table...yes ofcourse i order them by ID and they have false order.. did i need to commit the persist before moving to another persist and how ??

Answer (score 0):

There is no ordering in tables, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries) and other links there.

If you need an order on the `listofplusieurdrapage`, you must specify the ordering, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643641/saving-order-of-a-list-in-jpa).